# Attribute being removed by compiler, but I can't see why

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm trying to write a set of shaders to do per-vertex lighting with multiple lights, and textures.  I think I'm running into the shader compiler optimizing out 'v_texture', one of my attribute variables, because glVertexAttribLocation is failing to find it.

Here's my vertex shader code:

```
attribute vec3 v_position;
attribute vec3 v_normal;
attribute vec2 v_texture;

varying vec4 color;
varying vec2 texCoord;

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 8;

uniform struct lightSource
    {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 color;
    vec3 coneDirection;
    float coneAngle;
    float ambientFactor;
    } sceneLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform float shininess;
uniform int numLights;

vec4 applyLight(lightSource light)
{
vec4 outColor;
float attenuation;

vec3 surfacePos = (modelView * vec4(v_position.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;

vec3 toLight;

if(light.position.w == 0.0)
    {
    toLight = normalize(light.position.xyz);
    attenuation = 1.0;
    }

else
    {
    toLight = normalize(light.position.xyz - surfacePos);

    float distanceToLight = length(light.position.xyz - surfacePos);
    float lightAngle = degrees(acos(dot(-surfacePos, normalize(light.coneDirection))));

    if(lightAngle > light.coneAngle)
        {
        attenuation = 0.0;
        }

    else
        {
        attenuation = 1.0/(1.0 + (0.1 * pow(distanceToLight, 2.0)));
        }
    }

vec3 Eye = normalize(-surfacePos);
vec3 Halfway = normalize(toLight + Eye);

vec3 worldNormal = normalize(modelView * vec4(v_normal, 0.0)).xyz;

vec4 ambient = vec4(light.ambientFactor * vec3(light.color.xyz), 1.0);

float Kd = max(dot(toLight, worldNormal), 0.0);
vec4 diffuse = Kd * light.color;

float Ks = pow(max(dot(worldNormal, Halfway), 0.0), shininess);
vec4 specular = Ks * light.color;
if(dot(toLight, worldNormal) < 0.0)
    {
    specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

outColor = ambient + (attenuation * (diffuse + specular));
outColor.a = 1.0;
return outColor;
}

void main(void)
{
vec4 colorSum;

colorSum = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
    if(i >= numLights)
        {
        break;
        }
    colorSum += applyLight(sceneLights[i]);  
    }

colorSum.xyzw = normalize(colorSum.xyzw);

vec3 gammaCorrection = vec3(1.0/2.2);
color = vec4(pow(vec3(colorSum.xyz), gammaCorrection), 1.0);

texCoord = v_texture;

gl_Position = Projection * modelView * vec4(v_position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 color;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texSampler;

void main(void)
    {
    gl_FragColor = (color * texture2D(texSampler, texCoord.xy));
    }
```

I've been over the code top to bottom but I just can't see where my problem is.  I'm assigning v_texture to the texCoord, and passing it to the frag shader, where I'm using it together with the final lighting result from the vertex shader to yield the final color.  I'm checking for shader errors when I compile them, and I'm not getting anything.  My only guess at the moment is that maybe gl_FragColor = (color * texture2D(texSampler, texCoord.xy)) isn't a valid statement, but then shouldn't this have caught it?

```
glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
if (!shader_status) 
    {
    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Fragment Shader %d: '%s'\n", fragment_shader, InfoLog);
    }
```

Edit: I probably should have put this in here in the first place, but this snippet is the shader section from my C++ program's initialize() function.  The only one of the glGetAttribLocation calls to fail is for v_texture.

```
// Begin shader loading.
    //compile the shaders
GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
GLint shader_status;
pass=new char [2048];
unsigned int len;

//Give a maximum number of attempts to load the vertex shader 
int attempts=10;
//Load the vertex shader
do
    {

    loader.load("lighting.vsh");

    shaderCode = loader.hold.c_str();
    len=loader.length;
    pass=shaderCode;


    attempts-=1;
    }
while(len!=pass.length()&& attempts>0);

//Pass the temperary variable to a pointer
tmp = pass.c_str();


// Vertex shader first
glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1,&tmp, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
//check the compile status
glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
if (!shader_status) 
    {
    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Vertex Shader %d: '%s'\n", vertex_shader, InfoLog);
    }

const char *fs=loader.load("lighting.fsh");


// Now the Fragment shader
glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fs, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
//check the compile status
glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &shader_status);
if (!shader_status) 
    {
    GLchar InfoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, sizeof(InfoLog), NULL, InfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Fragment Shader %d: '%s'\n", fragment_shader, InfoLog);
    }

//Now we link the 2 shader objects into a program
//This program is what is run on the GPU
program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
glLinkProgram(program);
//check if everything linked ok
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &shader_status);
  if(!shader_status)
    {
    std::cerr << "[F] THE SHADER PROGRAM FAILED TO LINK" << std::endl;
    return false;
    }

//Now we set the locations of the attributes and uniforms
//this allows us to access them easily while rendering
loc_position = glGetAttribLocation(program,
                const_cast<const char*>("v_position"));

if(loc_position == -1)
    {
    std::cerr << "Error: POSITION NOT FOUND IN SHADER" << std::endl;
    return false;
    }

loc_normals = glGetAttribLocation(program, const_cast<const char*>("v_normal"));

if(loc_normals == -1)
    {
    std::cerr << "Error: NORMALS NOT FOUND IN SHADER" << std:: endl;
    return false;
    }


loc_texture = glGetAttribLocation(program, const_cast<const char*>("v_texture"));

if(loc_texture == -1)
    {
    std::cerr << "[F] TEXTURE NOT FOUND IN SHADER" << std::endl;
    return false;
    }


// Begin light initialization.
```

Comment: Have you tried to color debug your shader? 
Try:
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texCoord,0.0,1.0);

If you get different colors with this your mistake lies within the texture setup. If you get just one color you are passing the texCoords wrong

Comment: I just tried it, and glGetAttribLocation still returned -1.  Does that tell you anything?

Comment: It's funny; I see a lot of code here, but I don't see your actual call to glGetAttribLocation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mostly just put up my shader code because I thought that attributes getting culled by the compiler was common enough that the relevant part was whatever is going on in the shaders.  I'll edit some stuff in.

Comment: nothing looks wrong here. did you verify in the debugger that the shader passed to glShaderSource is the one you actually expect, with the v_texture in ? (ditto for the fragment shader)

Comment: I'm still kind of new to this.  How would I go about that?  I'm not really using an IDE for this, I've just been writing it with gedit.

Comment: I AM THE GREATEST PROGRAMMER KNOWN TO MAN! /s

So, I figured it out.  I was doing all this for an assignment at school, and when I was first working on the code, I used my last project as a guinea pig since it had fewer moving parts flying around so I could focus on getting the lighting right.  When I copy/pasted the work-in-progress to the new project's folder, I never actually re-opened the file in my editor, so all of the extra work I was doing was going into the folder for the _last_ assignment.

So, uh, my lights work now... >.<

Comment: that's why you need to learn to use a debugger :p It would have told you the code executed is not the one you're editing!